# Count empty mysql columns in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a method that counts the empty mysql columns.

My code is as follows:

```
public function countCompletion() {
        $userData = $this->find(Session::get('user'));
        $userData = $this->_data;

        $completion = 0;

        foreach($userData as $item) {
            if(empty($item)) {
                $completion++;
            }
        }

        die($completion);
    }
```

The problem is, when I die `$completion` it just shows nothing, while it should show 2.

Comment: Why are you using `die` instead of `return`?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax to test if `$completion` contains any data

Comment: Just to be sure, does your code actually call the function?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yep, I'm 100% sure it does

Comment: Have you tried substituting `$completion` with a literal to verify that your function is executing successfully? And do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: I don't think that's how `die` works. [According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php#refsect1-function.exit-parameters), if the `status` argument is an integer it isn't printed. Also, it terminates the entire script, not just the function that calls it.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I think that's the answer. I had forgotten that about integer exit parameters not being printed.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax That's it. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php#refsect1-function.exit-parameters), when `die` (or `exit`) is called with an integer argument the argument is not printed but is instead passed back to the operating system as an exit code. To get the value to display you will need to `return` it, then print it from the calling routine.

Answer (score 0):

first check with "echo" inside "foreach" to display column content then you can do a loop to incremente number of  empty column

```
    foreach($userData as $item) {
        echo 'data: '.$item.'<br>';
        if(empty($item)) {
            $completion++;
        }
    }
```

bacause you have to verify that your function is executing successfully

Comment: try this : 
if($item == "" or empty($item)) {
            $completion++;
        }

Answer (score 0):

you can use "var_dump()" also to test what variable contains

```
var_dump($completion);
die();
```